# how to print output of mutiple files side by side

Tags: linux

I have 4 files say:

```
cat test1
1 
2   
3

cat test2
4  
5  
6  

cat test3
7  
8  
9
```

I  need to display the content as below side by side:

```
1  4  7  
2  5  8  
3  5  9
```

I tried `pr -m -t test1 test2 test3`, but if if any value is large, the output is getting trim, I need to display the content according to the length of the value and should display the content side by side(column wise)

Comment: maybe better for unix SE?

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do it like :

```
cat *.txt | paste -d " " - - - | sed 's/_//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix)), for example:

```
$ cat test1 test2 test3 | paste -d " " - - -
```

From the man:

> If `-` is specified for one or more of the input files, the standard input is used; standard input is read one line at a time, circularly, for each instance of `-`.

So if you don't care about the order and let's say you would like to use all your `*.txt` files, you could simply do:

```
$ paste -d " " *.txt
```

You could also use [lam](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lam):

```
$ lam test1 -s " " test2 -s " " test3
```

Both examples use space as the separator `" "` and will output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: it's not working, still the alignment is missing, the data is not displaying correct

Comment: @SivaMalla what are you using as a separator, try tab `"\"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command which would not truncate the column values while printing:

pr -mJ test1 test2 test3 --sep-string="  ||  "

Answer (score 0):

to complete [nbari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496475/3214950) according your question:
`paste test1 test2 test3 | column -t`

P.S. for column greater than your screen size:
`paste test1 test2 test3 | column -t| less -S`